# Extract excel column values based on other column values using script

Tags: python, awk

I am having following excel sheet below:

[image: Data]

I need to segregate the data based on comment Column. If the Comment column value is same then I need to retrieve only name, port values as shown below:

```
###LSB Team
super_bot0,DstSdp00_Prb
super_tot0,DstSd_PrbAddr

###ESB Team
supe_bot0,IOHC_Vld
subot0_3,IOHC_DVMSyncComplete
```

Can anyone please help me to automate this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: In the first step I would export the data as CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run this on your excel file?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx')

comment_to_teams = {}
for comment, rows in df.groupby('Comment'):
    comment_to_teams[comment] = rows[['Name', 'Port']]

for comment, teams in comment_to_teams.items():
    print(comment)
    print(teams)
```

Comment: Please wait with an answer until he has shown what he has tried so far to solve the problem himself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Cyrus